# Cache - Image served from controller

Tags: symfony, controller, browser-cache

I have images that I'd like to serve to my users with a year of validity.

```
$file = $fileService->getFile($imageFilepath);
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => $file->getMimeType(),
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="img.'.$file->getExtension().'"'
);
$response = new Response(file_get_contents($file), 200, $headers);
$response->setExpires(new \DateTime('+1 year'));

return $response;
```

I can see from my browser console the headers are well set but the image is always `GET 200 OK`.

I also tried `Cache-Control` & `ETag`, still getting the image fetched from the server.

How can this happen ? **How can I return this image valid for a year ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use also a `$response->setLastModified()` method